Selenium WebDriverWait Fails to Detect Form Element for Submitting Answer on Embedded Video with Selenium
I have been programming a bot using Selenium to automate a tutorial series my school forces me to do.  In this tutorial there is one video which halfway through prompts the user with a form and some questions.  I have been attempting to use this code to wait while the video plays and until the form is visible
    WebDriverWait(driver, 1000).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, "answer_content_A11A59DC-2C74-11EE-83FC-C435C68A4852"))
    )



This ID is NOT visible at the start of the video, BUT once the form appears can be found.  However, the script never gets past the WebDriverWait() block.
I have also tried waiting based on the prescence of other elements but they seem to bring up the same problem.  Each time they get stuck on WebDriverWait().
Then I tried just waiting 30 seconds for the form to become visible, but this didn't work either.
    #Presses Play on Video
    driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME, "slip_button_icon").click()
    #Full duration of Video
    time.sleep(30)
    driver.find_element(By.ID, "answer_content_A11A59DC-2C74-11EE-83FC-C435C68A4852").click()


This error comes up even though when I command F the ID in my Selenium browser I am able to locate it.
An error occurred: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="answer_content_A11A59DC-2C74-11EE-83FC-C435C68A4852"]"}
(Session info: chrome=127.0.6533.72); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception

When I use XPATH I also get the same error An error occurred: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"/html/body/div/div/div/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/label/div/table/tbody/tr/td/table/tbody/tr/td[2]"}
(Session info: chrome=127.0.6533.72); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception

You have to confirm that the ID is not dynamically changing or being updated. Use browser developer tools to verify this or try other locators like By.CLASS_NAME, By.XPATH, By.CSS_SELECTOR.
Sometimes using presence_of_element_located might not be sufficient if the element is present but not yet visible or interactable. Consider using visibility_of_element_located:
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.ID, "answer_content_A11A59DC-2C74-11EE-83FC-C435C68A4852"))
)


Sometimes, it’s necessary to wait for specific JS events or to wait for the network to be idle. You might need to use JS execution to determine if the AJAX request is complete:
WebDriverWait(driver, 60).until(
    lambda d: d.execute_script('return document.readyState') == 'complete'
)

Some times the video located in a iframe and have to switch to that frame in order to capture the element.
WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(
    EC.frame_to_be_available_and_switch_to_it((By.TAG_NAME, "iframe"))  
)

